# Rails default_url_options for rake, delayed jobs etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

What's the best practice to set default url options site-wide in the Rails 4 app? It's simple to set them up for mailers in the development/production/... configs.

So I just added following as the first option:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: 'myhost.com' }
```

This was causing missing host in some situations so I removed Rails.application.routes from the configs and followed the [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default-url-options) to define a method in the application controller:

```
def default_url_options
  Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
end
```

However this doesn't work with things like Rake tasks, delayed jobs etc. that are not routed through controllers. So I had to add back Rails.application.routes to configs as well.

Now, the Rails.application.routes are specified on two places instead of one.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous jobs is a good question, you will probably have to do something similar to the following in the initialiser for the library you use.

You can specify in your application.rb config for both the mailers and controllers in a single place.

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { protocol:, host: , port: }
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { protocol:, host: , port: }
```

Injecting these into the default options at the start means each time a request (perhaps a link generator), it will find the options you supplied.

You will most likely want to overwrite the test environment `config/test.rb` with values that align with your test suite, e.g.

```
{ protocol: "http://", host: "test" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume what works for console will work for delayed jobs. Try this:

```
# in routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  default_url_options host:'myhost.com'

# in production.rb
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options= {host:'myhost.com'}
```

Please leave a comment to report whether this works or not :)